# How to use Delphi onKeyPress to make changes to a TImage, for example: to hind the image if certain is pressed down

Tags: image, delphi, keyboard, delphi-2010, onkeypress

I need to make a Timage item hide or disappear after a certain key is being pressed, while the program is still running.

I know that onKeyPress method can't really make changes to the Graphic items such like Timage, so is there any other alternative ways which I could use for my situation?

Comment: "*I know that onKeyPress method can't really make changes to the Graphic items*" - yes, it can, where did you get that idea from?

Answer (score 3):

Set `KeyPreview` of the form to `true` and write an `OnKeyPress|Down|Up` event for the form, where you hide that `TImage`.